# Validation vs focus lost

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

We're building a new application and one of requirements is 'no save button'. So each change of property is saved. To lower number of db transactions we would like only to save TextBox text after focus is lost.

Our problem is validation,
we normally use something like this:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This is not valid email address")]
public string UserEmail
{
    get { return userEmail; }

    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    set
    {
        Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) 
                                { MemberName = "UserEmail" }
                                );

        userEmail = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserEmail);
    }
}
```

This is only for

```
   binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
```

But in new solution - we would like to enter setter of 'UserEmail' property only when textbox is losing focus. But what about validation, it should work on each key press, how to acheive that?

Comment: What it comes down to is that you want 2 different events. I think you will need to set up a Caliburn message.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at the [System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) library, which includes an 'Interaction' class that works as an attached behaviour.
It allows you to essentially subscribe to whichever events you need to subscribe to. This would allow you to do validation 'on property changed' via a binding, just like you do now, and then do the actual DB call when the input field loses focus.
For a textbox, this might look something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextField, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

So essentially you 'de-couple' your save call from the actual 'setter' of the property. Something like this perhaps:

```
    private string textField;
    public string TextField
    {
        get { return textField; }
        set
        {
            if (value == textField) return;
            textField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ICommand saveCommand;

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get { return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save)); }
    }

    private void Save()
    {
       // Do your DB transactions here. 
    }
```

Comment: This will always force us to write at least twice as much of code as normally. 
This is indeed a solution, but we were hoping for something simpler.

Comment: You could create a behaviour that does all those things for you. Ie. subscribes to LostFocus on the control and then invokes a specified command, so that you end up with only one additional attached property you need to set on a textbox or similar.